# i have image handler and i was store my imnge in binary when i use handler i am resize image and display but i want to optimise my code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an image handler to resize and store images in Binary format.
Below is the handler code. I want to optimize this code, any help will be much appreciated.

```
 public class image : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Int32 StudentId;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        Int32 w;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["w"] != null)
            w = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["w"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        Int32 h;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["h"] != null)
            h = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["h"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");
        using (System.Drawing.Image img = ShowImage(StudentId))
        {
            byte[] bmpBytes;
            System.Drawing.Image pic = Resize(img, w, h);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); // better use a using statement
            pic.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bmpBytes);
            ms.Close();
            context.Response.End();
            img.Dispose();
        }


    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected System.Drawing.Image Resize(System.Drawing.Image img, int resizedW, int resizedH)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(resizedW, resizedH);
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)bmp);
        graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, resizedW, resizedH);
        graphic.Dispose();
        return (System.Drawing.Image)bmp;
    }
    public System.Drawing.Image ShowImage(int id)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyManageConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string sql = "SELECT StudentPhoto FROM tblStudent WHERE StudentId = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        connection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            //return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
            //return (byte[])img;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
            System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my image handler code.  we can direct convert to binary to image and resize.

```html
<asp:Image ID="imgStudentPhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"image.ashx?id="+Eval("StudentId")+"&w=200&h=200" %>' Height="60px" Width="60px"></asp:Image>
```

This `html` code in my grid-view. when I save image in binary format it size is mostly 3mb.

1. which one is the better way save original image or save resize image?
2. I want also ask save image in server is better or save in binary in `sql server` is better.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the image size is large then it's better to resize the image and save it.
2. The best way is to store image in a folder under the root directory of your project and save its path in database.